# reading one line delimited by both comma and space - java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am willing to read a series of number from one line like below in Java:

```
1   80,982  163,8164                    170,2620
```

So eventually I want the result array `[1, 80, 982, 163, 8164, 170, 2620]`

I am thinking about using scanner, but not clear how to implement it in a neat way, can I ask some tips please?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: @Amine nope, that class is nothing but legacy, and is discouraged in new code. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html

Comment: looking at the raw source of your question it appears that your line also contains tab (`'\t'`) characters. be sure to include that information in your question - it's important for the correctness of the answers you receive.

Comment: split uses a regex. `String.split("(\s*|,)")` or something should do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes the Scanner class works well with this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(strOrFile).useDelimiter(",| ");
    List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    while (s.hasNext()) {
       myList.add(s.nextInt());
    }
}
```

It works especially well if you're reading from a file. (Cuts down the work for you.)

Answer (score 6):

If it were me, I'd read one line using `BufferedReader` and then simply use

```
String[] values = line.split("[, ]");
```

I usually find `Scanner` untidy and overkill.

Comment: This won't work. His example could be delimited by " " or ","

Comment: @AthomSfere: The `[]` represents a character class, and in this case the regex can be read as "one character in the set `{<comma>, <space>}`".  Thus it should work perfectly fine.

Comment: Yeah I would go with this over Scanner if it's just one line :-)

Comment: I would accept this answer since less overhead. I would assume OP is using stdin. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Scanner is fine, just set the desired delimiter pattern, see [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#useDelimiter%28java.util.regex.Pattern%29).

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "1 80,982 163,8164 170,2620";
    String[] s = str.split(" |,");
    for(String ss:s)
        System.out.println(ss);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you want String[] the best solution is String.split

```
String[] s = str.split("[ ,]+");
```

Answer (score 2):

Split your string with below regex.

```
 String input = "1   80,982  163,8164                    170,2620 "; 
        String[] values = input.split("\\s*(,|\\s)\\s*");
        for(String val: values)
        {
            System.out.println(val);

        }
```

I matches following criteria.

1. Zero or more white space `(,|\\s)`. If you have more that one separator you can include in bracket like `(&|,|@|\\s)`.
2. Comma and white space.

Check the fiddle here.

[Java program](http://ideone.com/6ifrcC)

Answer (score 1):

```
    String ss = "1 80,982 163,8164 170,2620";
    ss = ss.replaceAll(" ", ",");
    String arr[] = ss.split(",");
    for (int i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
        System.out.println("line "+arr[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

For a simple input file with some commas, spaces, and commas with spaces, then regex of Rais and that of Evgeniy both worked with split. In the latter case, the + sign is critical. None of the other  options worked for this data:
1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0
5.0,6.0 7.0 8.0
9.0 10.0, 11.0 12.0